# Prevent monitor ghosting

Tags: display

Dear people on the internet,

Recently, I bought an iiyama ProLite X2474HS ([this one](https://iiyama.com/gb_en/products/prolite-x2474hs-b1/)) and I'm pretty happy with it. However, when doing a ghosting test ([this excellent test](https://www.testufo.com/ghosting)), it does appear to have the issue of ghosting. Normally, this only occurs with black surfaces (for example, black text ghosts when scrolling). How do I fix/prevent this?

PS: I won't be surprised if there's no fix for it. The monitor was quite cheap (130 euros).

System specifications:
GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1060 6GB
CPU: Intel Core i5 6400
Monitor is connected via DisplayPort. I tried HDMI, too.
OS: Ubuntu 17.10 with KDE installed

Comment: The problem is purely in the monitor, the only way to fix it is to buy a better monitor.

Comment: That's the answer I feared for... Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Sorry, we don't do hardware recommendations here. If you have a specific set of requirements and price then you might be able to ask at [hardwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 0):

While it's true that ghosting cannot be entirely fixed on some monitors, there is one thing that can reduce it noticeably.

Go to **Nvidia X Server Settings** > **GPU 0 Section** > **Your output (ex. HDMI-0)** > **Controls tab**.

Here look at **Color controls** and switch **Color Range** from *Full* to *Limited*. Possibly adjust also **Color space** to whichever looks better.

After this you may notice that colors on your monitor are a bit worse – not so bright and clear, a little washed out – but ghosting got much more tolerable. That's exactly the case, monitor wasn't able to keep up when processing full range color information on rapidly changing pixels.

Comment: I don’t think that’s a good idea. By doing this, you severely limit the color accuracy on your display. This setting is for displays that actually expect the reduced color range.

Comment: You're perfectly right - color accuracy will be limited - but for me it is a bearable thing compared to heavy ghosting. I currently have (almost) the same setup with _GTX 1060 6GB_ and _iiyama X2775HDS_ – limiting color range made it usable for me.

Comment: This was the best solution I found so far, yes it is looking a bit worst but now I can play my games without leaving traces in the entire screen!